# parallel-ssh with Passphrase Protected SSH Key

Tags: ssh, key-authentication, parallel-ssh

I'd like to use my passphrase protected SSH key when performing tasks with `parallel-ssh` (and related tools). However, I can't get this to work.

All the documentation, regarding `parallel-ssh`, show that I should be able to use `--askpass` or `-A` to do this:

```
-A
--askpass
      Prompt  for  a  password  and pass it to ssh.  The password may be 
      used for either to unlock a key or for password authentication.  The 
      password is transferred in a fairly secure manner (e.g., it will not 
      show up in argument lists).  However, be aware that a root user on 
      your system could potentially intercept the password.
```

However, when I enter the passphrase of my key, it doesn't work:

```
$ parallel-ssh --hosts=machines --user=my_user --askpass \
    --timeout=0 --inline -v 'sudo apt-get update'
Warning: do not enter your password if anyone else has superuser
privileges or access to your account.
Password: 
[1] 09:59:36 [FAILURE] amritiii Exited with error code 255
Stderr: Enter passphrase for key '/home/nhaigh/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Permission denied (publickey,password).
[2] 09:59:37 [FAILURE] gbdev Exited with error code 255
Stderr: Enter passphrase for key '/home/nhaigh/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Permission denied (publickey,password).
[3] 09:59:37 [FAILURE] code Exited with error code 255
Stderr: Enter passphrase for key '/home/nhaigh/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Permission denied (publickey,password).
[4] 09:59:37 [FAILURE] apollo Exited with error code 255
Stderr: Enter passphrase for key '/home/nhaigh/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Permission denied (publickey,password).
[5] 09:59:37 [FAILURE] odin Exited with error code 255
Stderr: Enter passphrase for key '/home/nhaigh/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Permission denied (publickey,password).
[6] 09:59:37 [FAILURE] hathor Exited with error code 255
Stderr: Enter passphrase for key '/home/nhaigh/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Permission denied (publickey,password).
[7] 09:59:37 [FAILURE] ldap Exited with error code 255
Stderr: Enter passphrase for key '/home/nhaigh/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Permission denied (publickey,password).
[8] 09:59:37 [FAILURE] thor Exited with error code 255
Stderr: Enter passphrase for key '/home/nhaigh/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Permission denied (publickey,password).
[9] 09:59:37 [FAILURE] bioserver Exited with error code 255
Stderr: Enter passphrase for key '/home/nhaigh/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

I've confirmed that my SSH key and passphrase work on each of the machines so I have no idea how to get this working.

Comment: I'm assuming that parallel-ssh is the same as pssh?

Comment: Yes, `parallel-ssh` and `pssh` are indeed the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `parallel-ssh` and `pssh` are equivalent then yes what you're attempting to do should work just fine with piping the passphrase in using the `-A` switch.

#### Example

Here's an example where I connect to 2 different systems, `host1` and `host2`. I use the `-l` switch to `pssh` to provide a default user of `root`. However on `host2` I override this in the `-H` switch by specifying the hostname as `user1@host2`.

```
$ pssh -A -i -H "host1 user1@host2" -l root 'echo "hi"'
Warning: do not enter your password if anyone else has superuser
privileges or access to your account.
Password: 
[1] 21:38:00 [SUCCESS] user1@host2
hi
Stderr: 
This is a private site.  Unauthorized connections are prohibited.  
All activity may be logged.  Disconnect immediately if you object to 
this policy or are not an authorized user.

X11 forwarding request failed on channel 1
Killed by signal 1.
[2] 21:38:00 [SUCCESS] host1
hi
Stderr: 
This is a private site.  Unauthorized connections are prohibited.  
All activity may be logged.  Disconnect immediately if you object to 
this policy or are not an authorized user.

ControlSocket /home/user1/.ssh/master-user1@ssh-tunnel.mydomain.com:22 already exists, disabling multiplexing
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
Killed by signal 1.
```

When the above works you'll notice the output of the command I'm running, `echo "hi"`.

#### Your issue

The problem you're running into with a passphrase on your SSH key pair is due to a bug. This is the bug titled: [Issue 80: Not passing passphrase?](https://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/issues/detail?id=80). The 4th comment to that issue shows a patch:

*excerpt*

> #### #4 robine...@gmail.com
>
> I changed the line to
>
> ```
>   if not ( prompt.strip().lower().endswith('password:') or 
>         'enter passphrase for key' in prompt.strip().lower()):
> ```
>
> and it seems to work

#### References

- [PSSH : Parallel SSH to execute commands on a number of hosts](http://zaman4linux.blogspot.com/2012/09/pssh-parallel-ssh-to-execute-commands.html)

Comment: Thanks for your input slm. `parallel-ssh` and `pssh` are indeed the same. I wasn't asking if it was possible - the documentation makes it clear that it is possible. I'm having trouble with actually getting it to work as it is documented.

Comment: @NathanS.Watson-Haigh - see update. It's a bug, I've ref'd the patch.

Comment: This is indeed the issue which is affecting me. However, since the authors of `parallel-ssh` are still unsure how best to detect the password prompt question and thus respond with the password/phrase entered, I'm going to stick with my keychain method. I wouldn't want my passphrase to be inadvertantly revealed to the wrong question prompt.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer as you managed to figure out that this was a known bug in the way `parallel-ssh` passes the passphrase to `SSH`. However, for those who come across this question in future, this bug may have been fixed or you may choose not to edit the `askpass_client.py` file. In either case, you can get around this using the `keychain` answer (http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128998/57414) or the ssh-agent answer (http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129022/57414)

Answer (score 5):

I managed to get this working by installing `keychain` rather than manually patching the [bug](https://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/issues/detail?id=80) causing my issues.

## Install and Manually Run keychain

```
# install keychain package
$ sudo apt-get install keychain

# add my key to the keychain, entering passphrase when asked
$ keychain ~/.ssh/id_rsa

# source the file generated by the above command
$ . ~/.keychain/$(uname -n)-sh
```

## Run Command without Password/Passphrase Input

Now this time I don't need my passphrase when calling `parallel-ssh` as the keychain takes care of the authentication:

```
$ parallel-ssh --hosts=machines --user=my_user --timeout=0 'sudo apt-get update'
[1] 14:52:15 [SUCCESS] amritiii 
[2] 14:52:17 [SUCCESS] odin
[3] 14:52:25 [SUCCESS] gmod
[4] 14:53:11 [SUCCESS] bioserver
[5] 14:53:14 [SUCCESS] thor
[6] 14:53:14 [SUCCESS] apollo
[7] 14:53:16 [SUCCESS] gbdev
[8] 14:53:17 [SUCCESS] code
[9] 14:53:18 [SUCCESS] hathor
[10] 14:53:34 [SUCCESS] ldap
```

## Run keychain on login

Rather than having to manually run and add your key to the keychain, simply add the following to the end of your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
$ keychain --clear $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
$ . $HOME/.keychain/$(uname -n)-sh
```

This ensures that on your first login, following a reboot, you are prompted for your key's passphrase. Your key will then stay in the keychain till the next reboot or you clear the keychain manually.

## Cron Jobs Using the keychain

With the above entered into your `~/.bash_profile` file, you can take advantage of the fact you're key is now stored in the keychain by souring the same file before your cronjob is run. For example I have a backup script which runs at 21:00 each night and copies stuff to a remote computer via SSH. This is an entry in my crontab (`crontab -e`):

```
 0 21 * * * . $HOME/.keychain/$(uname -n)-sh; $HOME/backup_script.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the **ssh-agent** to authenticate automatically ( with a shell name as argument to have the agent environment variables set in that new shell). 
Add the key with **ssh-add** and type your password only once.

```
$ ssh-agent bash
$ ssh-add
Enter passphrase for /xxxx/.ssh/identity: 
$ 
$ pssh ...
```